# Selenium unable to read all rows in excel sheet

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Excel sheet have 333 rows data, but selenium is able to read only 331 rows, I am running it in eclipse and using Apace poi.

Can anyone please help to resolve ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question with a [mcve]. You might also want to look for more relevant tags - I've removed the irrelevant and wrong [tag:apache] tag.

Comment: I know why, it is in your `code`, so show the code and will tell you the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.